# Query partial match in an array in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed data in the following format:

```
PUT /index/..
   {'keywords' => [
      {'keyword' => 'foo', 
       'keyword' => 'bar'}
   ]}
```

Then I want to get data objects that have `keyword` being `foo` inside `keywords`. I've tried:

```
 GET /index/..
  { query: {
      match: {
        'keyword' => 'foo'
    }
  }
```

and

```
  GET /index/..
   { query: {
      term: {
        'keywords.keyword' => 'foo'
    }
  }
```

But it didn't return the object from `PUT`, what is the right partial match query in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`"keyword":"foo"` gets overwritten with `"keyword":"bar"` when the document is indexed, since the inner object can only have one field with the name `"keyword"`.

To demonstrate, I created an index and saved a document like you posted:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "keywords": [
        {
            "keyword": "foo",
            "keyword": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then when I search for all docs, this one is returned:

```
POST /test_index/_search
...
{
   "took": 50,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "keywords": [
                  {
                     "keyword": "bar"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So your match query doesn't match the document because `keywords.keyword` is not set to `"foo"`.

Here is one way you can do this instead. If you keep the two keywords in separate inner objects in the `"keywords"` list, your query will work as expected:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "keywords": [
        { "keyword": "foo" },
        { "keyword": "bar" }
    ]
}

POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "keywords.keyword": {
            "value": "foo"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.19178301,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.19178301,
            "_source": {
               "keywords": [
                  {
                     "keyword": "foo"
                  },
                  {
                     "keyword": "bar"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/763a939d6146eb7a43c5e19e5bfd261a88fddf7b